# Prevent .htaccess files within subdirectories from being executed

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload

I have a service where a user is allowed to upload anything they please.  I have code execution and others disabled, but I cannot find a way to prevent a .htaccess file they upload from executing.

Comment: is the uploading script coded with php?

Comment: htaccess files don't execute. They are passive files that have a set of rules the server reads permanently. So, you can't prevent their execution. You should prevent them to be uploaded, though.

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA Actually you can make then "useless". See my answer

Comment: @WebnetMobile: Of course, but the OP was asking for a way to block their **execution**. Hence, my comment. I agree with your answer.

Comment: Correct - they are not executable nor executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **always** rename user uploaded files! If you do not do that, user can easily upload `hack.php` and then launch it to get your site hacked or abused. So this is in fact your problem.

Rename your files after upload. Keep original name (along with i.e. size, mime type etc) in database and route file download/view via the script which would take that original name from DB and build proper headers and then `file()` content of that file to the user. That would prevent a file from being executable on your server

Or if that's the problem with `.htaccess` only (but I dare to say it is wider) then you can configure apache to ignore .htaccess in certain directories. It requires root rights on the machine, but you can add `<Directory FOLDER>` block to host configuration and put [`AllowOverride None`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in it.

Or, just check target filename on upload and reject any `.htaccess` and `.htpassword`. Or anything with name starting with `.`

Comment: Executing of PHP and other normally executed files are disallowed.  I'm just wondering how to disable their .htaccess files from being checked by Apache.

Comment: Yes, you can configure apache to ignore .htaccess in certain directories. It requires root rights on the machine, and then you add `<Directory FOLDER>` block and put `AllowOverride None` in it.

Comment: Can I tell it to ignore all .htaccess's besides the one in the root directory?

Comment: Yes, you can. See `Directory` or `DirectoryMatch` in apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory